# how to get kafka lag using java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have currently developed a code that would display the topic, partition, and log offset. But I am currently stuck on how to get the Lag of a partition. I know that there is a kafka offset command that does this function but what I need is a java code.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("START CONSUMER");final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_PLAINTEXT");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUPID);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

    // Create the consumer using props.
    final Consumer<Long, String> consumer =  new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

    // Subscribe to the topic.
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<TopicPartition> partitions = new ArrayList<TopicPartition>();
    for (i=0;i<consumer.partitionsFor(TOPIC).size();i++)
    {
        TopicPartition partitiontemp = new TopicPartition(TOPIC, i);
        partitions.add(partitiontemp);
    }
    consumer.assign(partitions);
    consumer.seekToEnd(partitions);

    for (i=0;i<consumer.partitionsFor(TOPIC).size();i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Topic: %s partitionID: %d log offset: %d \n", TOPIC, i, consumer.position(partitions.get(i)));
    }

    System.out.printf("CREATE CONSUMER DONE");
    consumer.close();
```

[image: This is the output of my code]

What I need to do is to output the topic, partition, current offset, log offset, and lag. How can I get the lag for my code or how can I get the current offset for my code. (see image for needed output).

[image: Needed output]

NOTE: I cannot use the (foreach record) functionality because I must not read each record in the input file.

Comment: Why is the needed output tabbed differently?

Comment: The Kafka offset command also runs Java (actually Scala), and the source code for it is on Github, if you just want to reproduce it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get kafka consume lag in java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program)

Answer (score 6):

To reproduce the `kafka-consumer-groups` functionality, you need both a Consumer and an AdminClient instance.

First, use the AdminClient, you can call [`listConsumerGroupOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listConsumerGroupOffsets-java.lang.String-) to retrieve the list of topic-partitions and the committed offsets for a specific group.

Then use a Consumer to get the End offsets for these partitions. The method you used is inefficient, there's no need to assign and seek to the end offset. You can simply call [`endOffsets()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#endOffsets-java.util.Collection-).

That is enough for reproducing the data contained in your screenshot.

`kafka-consumer-groups` also uses [`AdminClient.describeConsumerGroups()`](http://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#describeConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-) to print the group member assigned (if any) to each partition.

Comment: Does consumer.endOffsets competes with the other consumers from different group when it request end offsets ? Is asking for latest offset is same as consuming messages behind the scenes ? Does it cause rebalancing ?Also see if you would be interested in answering question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52864617/2683814). Appreciate the reply. Thanks!

Comment: `endOffsets()` does not require a consumer group so no rebalancing. Also it does not involve consuming any messages. That's why it's way more efficient than the logic you posted.

Comment: Thanks Mickael. What about `listConsumerGroupOffsets` ? I've very busy performance sensitive topic with 10 partition with 10+ consumers each consuming messages from application A. Will be affecting their processing anyways when I made `listConsumerGroupOffsets` request from application  B ? What other things if any I should be mindful when collecting offset metrics ? Thanks!

Comment: `listConsumerGroupOffsets()` simply sends an `OffsetFetch` request. It won't affect existing groups and its performance cost is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

You can have LAG by getting EndOffset from consumer

```
Set<TopicPartition> partitionSet = consumer.assignment();
Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets =consumer.endOffsets(consumer.assignment());
```

then iterate where over set

```
for(TopicPartition tp : partitionSet) { LOG.info("Topic :: {} ,EndOffset :: {}, currentOffset {}",tp.topic(),beginningOffsets.get(tp),endOffsets.get(tp), consumer.position(tp)); }
```

consumer.position(tp) -- will get you current offset, subtract this from endoffset , you get LAG

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static long calculateTopicLag(Properties properties, String topic, String consumerGroup) {
        try (AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties)) {
            ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult groupOffsetsResult = adminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets(consumerGroup);
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = groupOffsetsResult.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();

            long topicLag = 0;
            for (Map.Entry<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> entry : offsets.entrySet()) {
                TopicPartition topicPartition = entry.getKey();
                long consumerOffset = entry.getValue().offset();

                KafkaConsumer<?, ?> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
                consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
                long endOffset = consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition)).get(topicPartition);
                consumer.close();

                long partitionLag = endOffset - consumerOffset;
                topicLag += partitionLag;
            }

            return topicLag;
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello! It would be great if you could add more details to explain how this code helps answer the question. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/34851743)